# How to change this IF to allow selection between two numbers only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jQuery script and the main part is below. It allows me to select up to 4 items. Until there are 5 selections made, there is an error message.

How can I change this so that the error message appears if the choices are less than 2 and more than 5, and the success message is shown when the choices are between them?

```
if ($(this).multiselect("widget").find("input:checked").length > 5) {
    warning.addClass("error").removeClass("success").html("You can only check two checkboxes!");
    return false;
} else {
    warning.addClass("success").removeClass("error").html("Check a few boxes.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the number of checked items in to a local variable and then use a compound `if` statement that does multiple comparisons on it:

```
var checkedItemsLength = $(this).multiselect("widget").find("input:checked").length;
if(checkItemsLength < 2 || checkItemsLength > 5 ) {
    warning.addClass("error").removeClass("success").html("You can only check two checkboxes!");
    return false;
} else {
    warning.addClass("success").removeClass("error").html("Check a few boxes.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selections = $(this).multiselect("widget").find("input:checked");
if(selections.length < 2) {
     warning.addClass("error").removeClass("success").html("You have to check atleast two checkboxes!");
     return false;
} else if (selections.length > 5) {
     warning.addClass("error").removeClass("success").html("You can not check more then five checkboxes!");
     return false;
} else {
     warning.addClass("success").removeClass("error").html("Check a few boxes.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSomeChecking() {
  // assuming 'warning is a reference to some div or span
  var warning = $('#warning');
  var numChecked = $(this).multiselect("widget").find("input:checked").length;
  if (numChecked > 5) {
    warning.addClass("error").removeClass("success").html("You cannot check more than five boxes!");
    return false;
  } else if (numChecked < 2) {
    warning.addClass("error").removeClass("success").html("You must check at least two boxes.");
    return false;
  }
  warning.addClass("success").removeClass("error").html("Life is good.");
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(foo < 2 || foo > 5){

   //do something

  }else {

  //do something else

  }
```